# How to use firebase dynamic links to navigate to a specific screen in my app?

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, react-native-firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-deep-linking

I've some basic ideas of how firebase dynamic links works, but I've some doubts.
I didn't understand how to navigate it to a specific screen when I get the URL. I want to send some params along with the URL.

I have two screens

Home Screen.

Product Screen contains these screen.

- Product 1
- Product 2
- Product 3

I have to create dynamic links while sharing the products and then while opening the link I need to pass some routes to get the specific screen. Is there a way to send a params through firebase dynamic links ?

Comment: This might help you: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links

Comment: I read some of those docs but I've a question how can I able create dynamic links with parameters dynamically using code ?